# C++ classes with members referencing each other and being used

Tags: c++, include

I have 2 c++ classes with members referencing each other. I am calling members of the referenced classes, so I can't use forward declarations, because I get the error "pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed"

```
class A {
    B* b;

    void foo() { 
        b->do_something(); 
    }
};

class B {
    A* a;

    void bar() { 
        a->do_something_else(); 
    }
};
```

Is there any way to get the includes to work here?

There is already a ticket open by a similar name but I can't use the solution there.

Comment: Why you can't use forward declaration? Please, show how your classes are divided into files?

Comment: You probably need to forward declare, and then move the function definitions of `foo` and `bar` into your source files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just separate the definitions from the declarations:

```
class B;
class A {
public:
    void foo();
    void do_something_else(){}
private:
    B* b;
};
class B {
public:
    void bar();
    void do_something(){}
private:
    A* a;
};

//now B has a complete type, so this is fine
void A::foo() {
    b->do_something();
}

//ditto
void B::bar() {
    a->do_something_else();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the prototype definitions in a header file. And the logical body in a cpp file.

After doing this you can use the forward declaration in the header( class B, class A)

Example: @TartanLlama